# Customized Vertical Tab bars in iphone

Tags: iphone, tabs

I am new to iphone development. Can anyone tell me how to implement a vertical tab bar? I want something that looks like the tab bar on the right side of the screenshot in this link http://michelangelo.com/2011/11/nps-national-mall/ with the overview, events and other options displayed in the image. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried to add images as icons and tried to make it look like a vertical tab bar. But, it wasn't that effective...

Comment: I started to work on iphone just a week ago. So, please don't mind if my question is too basic...

Comment: It's not too basic, it's just that it really helps to know what you have tried, what the code is, and what doesn't work about it. Otherwise it comes across as you just asking for people to write your code for you, which is not wha this site is for.

Comment: I'm not asking the code. I jus' want to know the procedure of how to implement this. I even tried to find tutorials but couldn't find what I was actually looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tabbar is nothing more then a bunch of buttons next to eachother where one (or none) button has a 'selected' state. To create a vertical tab-bar: Simply place a few buttons below each other and attach corresponding listeners from those buttons to your viewcontroller (delegate).

Everytime you press one of these buttons all the buttons go into the 'default' state and the button you pressed changes to 'selected' state. After that you can load a new view with (for instance) a `UINavigationController`